# have someone/something be

Tags: verbs

The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (p 1236) marks ungrammatical the construction of "have something/someone + be + past participle":

> *He had his son be examined by a specialist.

CGEL seems to say that the "be" needs to go to make it grammatical:

> He had his son examined by a specialist.

Now, here's an excerpt from a Guardian article titled "[Congress seeks to lift gun ban at military outposts despite army's concerns](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2015/jul/28/congress-loosen-gun-restrictions-military-outposts-chattanooga)",

> USARC, he added, would not be involved in changes to firearm policies and would continue to follow the directive issued by the military. But Lepley echoed Rooney’s view that recruiting stations must remain in high-traffic areas where young men and women could be easily recruited.
>
> “We can’t **have recruiting stations be** like a fortress, we can’t **have them be** barricaded,” he said. “It’s not very welcoming. People need to be able to find us and come talk to us.”

The portion that Brian Lepley, a spokesman for the US army recruiting command (USARC), was quoted as saying includes the construction "have ... be". Is the construction well formed?

If so, how do I distinguish the ungrammatical CGEL example from the utterance of the USARC spokesman?

Comment: There's a difference in the predicates and therefore the constructions involved. The first _have_ construction requires an active predicate because it's a causative,  and doesn't allow _to be_ normally (_He had his tires rotated/*to be rotated_). That's not possible with the second construction, which has a stative predicate and is therefore not the same usage as the firs; it has its own rules (which allow _to be_ to be retained).

Comment: @JohnLawler I was asking about the bare infinitive _be_, not _to be_.

Comment: That's an `Act` _be_, as in _Why not (go) be examined by a specialist?_ or _I had him (go) be examined by a specialist._  or _I made him (go) be examined by a specialist._.

Comment: @JohnLawler Sorry but I don't get what you mean by "Act be." Do you mean _be_ in your examples denotes an action? Why did you put _(go)_ in your examples? Also, what's "Act be" got to do with inserting _to be_ instead of _be_ in your earlier example (*_He had his tires to be rotated_)?

Comment: I mean that it's a required auxiliary verb for an active nonverbal predicate, and therefore means if anything, 'act in a particular way', as in _Be honest, She's just being devious, He's just being a dick_. That's why they can occur in imperatives and progressives. That way they can also occur as complements to the small verbs that don't require _to_ before infinitive complements.

Answer (score 3):

The word "**have**" in the two examples has two different meanings.

In your first example, it means "**arrange for** his son **to be**"

> He **arranged for** his son **to be** examined by a specialist.
> He **had** his son examined by a specialist.

In the second example, it means "**let**."

> We can't **let** recruiting stations be like a fortress
> We can’t **have** recruiting stations be like a fortress
>
> We can't **let** them be barricaded.
> We can't **have** them be barricaded.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't understand why _we can’t have them be barricaded_ cannot be interpreted as "we can't arrange for them to be barricaded".

Answer (score 0):

You distinguish

> "*He had his son be examined by a specialist"

and

> "He had his son examined by a specialist"

(the second, corrected, requiring an active predicate (per John Lawler) 
and the second set,

> “We can’t have recruiting stations be like a fortress, we can’t have
>   them be barricaded,"
>   by the existence of the word can't, which changes the role of "have" in the sentence(s) and allows a stative predicative:
>   Stations can't be like fortresses; stations can't be barricaded;

we can't have that;

> we can't have stations be like fortresses, we can't have them be
>   barricaded.

This is different from saying

> "We can't arrange for them to be barricaded,"

which means something else entirely:  The inability (for reasons of lack of money or lack of manpower or community opposition) to have them barricaded, not the unacceptability of having them be barricaded, which is the point the speakers were trying to make.

Well, that may not help.  Just a try.

Answer (score 0):

Constructions such as '*He had his son examined by a specialist*' involve the causing of an action to happen.

Conversely, the context of the construction '*we can’t have them be barricaded*' seems to be referring not to an action, but to a state. It means '*we cannot have recruiting stations that are barricaded*' It is not referring to the action of having someone put up barricades.

The *be-construction* here is similar to utterances such as:

> - We cannot have them be unhappy. (i.e., in the state of unhappiness)
> - We cannot have them be disappointed.

The problem here is that past participle forms such as *disappointed, embarrassed, barricaded* etc. are used both as verbs in passive constructions and as adjectives in simple copulas. For example:

> - I was disappointed.
> - She was embarrassed.
> - The recruiting station was barricaded.

That said, there are numerous examples in Google of the '*have them be*' + past participle which do indeed refer to actions not states. A common example is '*[have them be killed](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22have%20them%20be%20killed%22&oq=%22have%20them%20be%20killed%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.3562j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)*':

> - You grow attached to character only to *have them be killed* ... later
>   in the storyline.
> - She slayed her children upon the altar in the Temple rather than *have
>   them be killed* by Christians or Muslims during the siege of Jerusalem.

In the above sentences, neither '*you*' nor '*she*' is causing the killing to happen. To omit the *'be'* in each case would change the meaning of the sentence. Conversely, in the following, there **is** a causative action, and the *'be'* could be omitted with no change of sense:

> - You have to kill every human (or *have them be killed* by an enemy).
>
> He got back his parents and was forced to *have them be killed* again.

You can decide for yourself if this superfluous use of *'be'* is grammatical.